# What does a continue in an always block do?

Tags: system-verilog

I came across a piece of code where there was a `continue` inside an `always` block. For example:

```
always @(posedge clk) begin
    count = count + 1;
    if(count[0])
        continue;
    $display("count: ",count);
end
```

I am not able to understand how this `continue` works here as in my opinion `continue` is only applicable when used in a loop. Please tell anything related to it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to IEEE Std 1800-2017, section 12.8 *Jump statements:*

```
The continue and break statements can only be used in a loop.
```

Since the `continue` statement is not inside a loop (such as a `for` or `while` loop), it is illegal syntax.  Several simulators on [edaplayground](https://www.edaplayground.com/x/jSDd) generate compile errors.  If you do not get an error, your simulator does not comply with the standard, and your code will not be portable with other simulators.  Also, since it is explicitly forbidden in the standard, its behavior is undefined.